# Почему не вылетает StackOverflowError?

Tags: stacktrace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   startRecursion();
}

private static void startRecursion(){
    System.out.println("StackTrace deep is " + getStackTraceDeep());
    startRecursion();
}

public static int getStackTraceDeep() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length;
}
```

Почему в данном примере не вылетает стэк овер флоу, и почему он вылетает если убрать строку System.out.println ?

Comment: "вылетает" - просто этого надо дольше ждать

Comment: время идет на вывод в консоль сообщения - стек медленней забивается

Comment: Точно! Интересно, что длинна стэка доходит до 1024 и дальнейший рост не показывает. Если дольше подождать - он доходит до 7000 (приблизительно) и вылетает ошибка.